# Windows telnet script with @ in the username

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, telnet

I'm trying to script the telnet command to log into a server. My problem is that my username is my email so it has an @ in it - so something like this fails:

```
telnet user@email.com@1.1.1.1
```

I've also tried this but it fails the same way.

```
set USER=user@email.com
telnet %USER%@1.1.1.1
```

Is there any way to escape the ampersand or is there another way to pass it to the telnet command? I've tried passing -l as follows but it does not work (as it still prompts me for a username so I'm guessing the telnet server doesn't support that and that would be out of my control to change).

```
telnet -l user@email.com 1.1.1.1
```

Ultimately, my goal is to get a doskey script with a command like the following

```
doskey t=telnet user@email.com@1.1.1.1
```

EDIT: Originally I mistakenly said ampersand but meant the at (@) symbol.

Comment: Good catch, my mistake! I mean the @ symbol.

Comment: Does the server accept your username in the format of `email.com\user`?  In the Windows world and in some LDAP queries, `user@domain` and `domain\user` mean the same thing.

Comment: No, unfortunately that does not seem to work.